# my code is wrong (list of str(1 element) into a int) error ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "['2']"

Tags: python, string, list, int

i want a make a program where you introduce you credit card number and says if is valid and what carrier but now i am having problems with the string this is the code,sorry is very messy:

```
number =raw_input("numero?")

 #revisa las posiciones
  number=number.split() 
  def check_sum(number):
     d = 0
     pe =str(number[0:1:1])
     posicion_impar = number[1::2]
     posicion_par= number[0::2]
     for x in posicion_par:
         f = int(x)
         d += f 
     for i in posicion_impar:
         z = int(i)
         if z < 5:     
             d += z*2

         elif z == 6:
              d = d + 3
         elif z == 7:
             d += 5
         elif z == 8:
             d += 16
         elif z == 9:
            d += 18

    if d % 2 != 0 and d % 5 != 0 :
         print "invalid"

    elif int(pe) == 4 and len(number)== 17 or len(number) == 14   :
          return "Visa"


    elif len(number) == 15 and int(pe) == 3:
    #american express 15
         return "American Express"

    elif len(number) == 17 and int(pe) == 5:
         return "Master-Card"




print check_sum(number)
```

the basics rules to now if is visa,always start with 4 and has 13 or 16 numbers
if is mastercard has 16 numbers and always start with 5
and if its american express always start with 3 and has 14 numbers

```
    error:
    File "work.py", line 33, in check_sum
       elif int(pe) == 4 and len(number)== 17 or len(number) == 14   :
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "['2']"
```

Comment: Can you post the input?

Comment: It looks like what you want to do is the [Luhn algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm).  The link has an implementation in Python and it worked for my Visa and Mastercard numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> number =raw_input("numero?")
> ```

At that point `number` is a string.

> ```
> number=number.split()
> ```

Now `number` is a list of strings. This is what you pass as an argument to the `check_sum` function.

> ```
> pe =str(number[0:1:1])
> ```

`number[0:1:1]` is a slice of the list `number`, containing a single element, the first one. You could write this as `[number[0]]`, i.e. make a new list containing one element which is the first element of `number`. Calling `str` builds a string representation of that list: for example, if the first element of `number` is the string `"1234"`, then `pe` is set to the 8-character string `"['1234']"`.

If you meant for `pe` to be the first element of the list of strings `number`. Thus:

```
pe = number[0]
```

If you meant for `pe` to be the first digit in the input, then that would be the first character of the first word:

```
pe = number[0][0]
```

I think there are other flaws in your code, for example `len(number)` is the length of the split list, not the number of digits in the input. If you expected the input to be only digits, don't call `split`, so that `number` is the input string which is the list of characters (without a final newline).

Comment: @DSM Thanks, I'd forgotten about that (in real life I always use `readline`, not `raw_input`).

Answer (score 0):

`pe` is a single-element list `"['2']"`. To extract the single string it contains, index into it:

```
int(pe[2])
```

Or, given that you create `pe` in the first place and never use it as a string, change how you do that:

```
     pe = int(number[0])
```

Comment: I think `pe` isn't a list but a string, but it's the `str` version of a one-element list whose element is a one-character string.  `pe[0]` would be `"["`, I think.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
pe =str(number[0:1:1])
```

Is causing pe to be a list. You probably want

```
pe = number[0]
```

Comment: `number[0]` is a string, calling `str` on it is redundant.